# How to link statically C++ dll to .NET library (build in c++ dll to net wrapper dll to get one dll)

Tags: c#

I have C++ dll. Than I wrote .NET Wrapper to this C++ dll, and I can attach .NET wrapper to my project and use C++ library in it. But now I have two files: c++.dll and wrapper.dll. The problem is with c++.dll, someone can replace c++.dll and inject its code to my application through wrapper.dll. How can I embed c++.dll to .net wrapper to get one .net wrapper dll?

Thanks

Comment: Then the wrapper.dll can be replaced too. Why would one DLL be any safer from malice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple: Don't.

You *could* bundle the C++ DLL into the .NET Assembly as a [resource](http://www.jelovic.com/articles/resources_in_visual_studio.htm) - but then these malicious users could just use ILDASM or Reflector or whatever to pull resources out of your .NET assembly - or decompile your .NET wrapper and recompile it with whatever code they want.

Bottom line is, you're really barking up a tree you can't climb (you can do things to dissuade people, but you're not going to stop them from messing with your app if they really want to) - and somehow merging your DLLs into one file really isn't going to give you any meaningful benefit.

Answer (score 0):

You could try merging them (with ILmerge, for instance), though I'm not sure how useful that would be. Then again, if you merge as many files as possible into one single file, that could help your security at least a bit. This might help: http://weblogs.asp.net/ralfw/archive/2007/02/04/single-assembly-deployment-of-managed-and-unmanaged-code.aspx

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Ok. It seems that it must remain as it is.